# Javascript NOT operator

Tags: javascript

Hello i am currently reading eloquent javascript and am confused on the not (!) operator between these two examples as the ! seems to contradict each case. My thought process sofar entails:

1.

```
var theNumber = Number(prompt("Pick a number", ""));
if (!isNaN(theNumber))
    alert("Your number is the square root of " +
    theNumber * theNumber);
```

if i give the var theNumber a value of 3, then isNaN(3) will return false and so the alert function will run. what is the condition for the if statement to run in this case?
2.

```
do {
var yourName = prompt("Who are you?");
} while (!yourName);
console.log(yourName);
```

if i give yourName a value of "George", console.log(yourName) will run if yourName evaluates to false but yourName will evaluate to true in this case becase "George" is a string.

Comment: the `!` gives the opposite boolean value. `! true` becomes `false` and  `! false` becomes true. So you can read `! isNaN` as " _not is NaN_ ". If the value is NaN, you have " _not true_ " which then means " _false_ ". Similarly when the value is not NaN: " _not is NaN_ " -> " _not false_ " -> " _true_ "

Comment: 1. isNaN = "Is it not a number?". So basically `isNaN(..)` = "Is it not numeric?", hence `!isNaN(..)` = "Is it a number?" - 2. What is your problem here?

Comment: so what is your question ? isNaN stands for 'is not a number'. If you give it a string that can be parsed into a number, it will return false. in your second case, a string passed into a boolean returns true. your loop ends because you use not operator. there is nothing that is not normal.

Comment: i understand the 1st part, i think i was confused on the second part, the while is supposed to loop the do function and not the console.log function right? so yourName will repeat the do function until it recieves a string right?

Comment: yes @kevin lu and it does so.

Answer (score 0):

The loop never exits until !yourName is false. So it exits only when yourName is true (so !yourName is false).  So console.log(yourName) will run **only when yourName evaluates to true**

Edit:
FYI:

```
if(true)   // evaluates to true and will run
if(!true)  // evaluates to false and is not run
if(!false) // evaluates to true and will run
```

I suggest you go through the explanation of logical operators online.

Comment: This is only a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general `!true === false`

1. isNaN = "Is it not a number?". So basically `isNaN(..)` = "Is it not numeric?", hence `!isNaN(..)` = "Is it a number?" -
2. It will ask you for names as long as (while) you enter anything that evaluates to false (e.g. if you enter nothing). `!<String>` evaluates to true. Hence once you enter something the while statement will evaluate as follows

`!yourName`-> `!"George"` -> `!true` -> `false` --> exit while

Answer (score 0):

isNaN stands for 'is not a number'. If you give it a string that can be parsed into a number, it will return false.

```
isNaN("1");  //false
isNaN("a");  //true
isNaN(2);    //false
```

so in the first case, there is no problem, it will run normally.

for the second case, a string, passed as a boolean returns true if not null. what you pass("George") returns true and you make it false with not operator. so the loop ends and writes to console. if you try to hit enter without writing anything to prompt, loop will continue.

everythings normal here. what exactly is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

1.

!isNaN(theNumber) translates to "Not (is Not a number)", so we can reduce the double Not, and it turns out: "is a number".

But, condition "if (typeof theNumber == 'number')" returns false, because 'prompt' retruns string '3', not a number. Function isNan converts argument to a number before checking.

Look on examples https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

2.

All right, it is type conversion. You should read this article to understand it 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Type_conversion

It two words: sometimes operator not (!)  is used for type conversion.
By the way, you can use double operator not.
Example:

```
!!'test string' // returns true
```